# What's the name of the storage paradigm that uses cubes subdivided into 8 smaller cubes ad infinitum?

Tags: data-structures, terminology

If I have a cube divided into 8 smaller cubes, each of which may be subdivided into a further 8 cubes, ad infinitum, what is the name of my system?

I know that it's a special case of a tree, where each brance contains exactly 8 other leaves/branches.

I remember the name starting with "Oct", and there was a wikipedia article on it, but I honestly can't find it!

Does anyone know what such a data structure is actually known as?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree)?

> An octree is a tree data structure in which each internal node has exactly eight children. Octrees are most often used to partition a three dimensional space by recursively subdividing it into eight octants.

Comment: Yes, that's _exactly_ the article I was looking for. Thanks a lot! (6 minutes till I can accept)

Comment: @Eric - Glad I could help, though all the hints were in the question... tree... eight children... oct something...

Comment: Yes, I can see that now that I know the answer!